# Umlaut (ä, ö, ü) on English (US) layout

Tags: windows, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout

The internet tells me, that I need to use the unicode-code to get those letters, but that can't seriously be the proper way to do it right? There must exist an easier solution (without 3rd party software).

Example of how to do it:

- alt + 148 ö (0246)
- alt + 137 ë (0235)
- alt + 132 ä (0228)

Is there a shortcut to those letters?

Comment: This is an easy way.  Why do you think there must be an easier one?

Comment: Alex. S You need to press 4 keys and need to remember the code. You think this is a conventient method? On my keyboard, this usually is a single press and it's done. With this method here, you (of course) even need to remember separade codes for the uppercase version (`ä` and `Ä` have a different code). :)

Comment: there is one thing of terminology... English doesn't have umlauts. Double dots above vowels in words like "naïve" or "reëlect" aren't umlauts, those are diaeresis even while in Unicode they are represented by same code (along with diacritic and hiatus)

Comment: There seems to be confusion between umlaut and tréma.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

#### Is there a shortcut to those letters?

Assuming you are using Windows then install the United States-International keyboard layout.

See below for instructions for Windows 7.

You can then use <kbd>"</kbd> followed by one of <kbd>e</kbd>, <kbd>y</kbd>, <kbd>u</kbd>, <kbd>i</kbd>, <kbd>o</kbd>, or <kbd>a</kbd> to produce <kbd>ë</kbd>, <kbd>ÿ</kbd>, <kbd>ü</kbd>, <kbd>ï</kbd>, <kbd>ö</kbd>, or <kbd>ä</kbd>

---

#### How to use the United States-International keyboard layout

> **Adding the United States-International keyboard layout**
>
> To add the United States-International keyboard layout, follow these
>   steps:
>
> - Click Start Start button, type intl.cpl in the Start Search box, and then press ENTER.
> - On the Keyboards and Language tab, click Change keyboards.
> - Click Add.
> - Expand the language that you want. For example, English (United States).
> - Expand Keyboard list, select the United States-International check box, and then click OK.
> - In the Default input language list, click Language name - United States-International (where Language name is the language that
>     you selected in step 4), and then click OK two times.
> - In the Regional and Language Options dialog box, click OK.
>
>   Notice that the Language bar appears on the taskbar. When you position the mouse pointer over it, a ToolTip appears that describes
>     the active keyboard layout.
> - Click the Language bar, and then click United States-International on the shortcut menu that appears.
>
>   The United States-International keyboard layout is selected.
>
> **Creating international characters**
>
> When you press the APOSTROPHE ( <kbd>'</kbd> ) key, QUOTATION MARK ( <kbd>"</kbd> ) key,
>   ACCENT GRAVE ( <kbd>`</kbd> ) key, TILDE ( <kbd>~</kbd> ) key, or ACCENT CIRCUMFLEX,. also
>   called the CARET key, ( <kbd>^</kbd> ) key, nothing is displayed on the screen
>   until you press a second key:
>
> - If you press one of the letters designated as eligible to receive an accent mark, the accented version of the letter appears.
> - If you press the key of a character that is not eligible to receive an accent mark, two separate characters appear.
> - If you press the space bar, the symbol (apostrophe, quotation mark, accent grave, tilde, accent circumflex or caret) is displayed by
>     itself.
>
> The following table shows the keyboard combinations that you can use
>   to create the desired character.
>
> [image]

[How to use the United States-International keyboard layout](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/306560)

Comment: The US Int’l keyboard layout is available on macOS and Linux, too, by the way. So it is *the* solution. ß is on RAlt+S.

Comment: @DanielB -  method of accessing international characters is not universal. This method works for Windows but will not work for Mac. Mac uses 'dead-keys' to access accents - for instance Opt/u then u will give ü. Opt/e then a will give á.

Comment: @Tetsujin I was referring to the keyboard layout. Of course it’s a little different on macOS (just because), but the general idea is still the same.

Comment: Mac doesn't have a 'US International' keyboard layout, only a 'US International - PC' layout, so no, it's not really all the same.

Comment: `"` - double quote is not the same as diaerisis; which is what you have in e.g. `ä`, `ö` and `ü`

Comment: @Hannu Please read the answer again. You need to press `"` **followed by another (plain) character** to get the character with the diaerisis (umlaut)

Comment: Read my comment again, I seriously doubt that pressing the **doubleqoute** will have ANY effect w.r.t. the above. There is an umlaut-marked key on the Swedish keyboard.

Comment: @Hannu Please read my answer again. I have tested it and it works. Note the OP is presumably **not** using a Swedish keyboard.

Comment: Alright, then that is specific to the keyboard you refer to, I'd guess there is no umlaut key on that then. `"` does NOT work in the described way on the Swedish nor Finnish keyboard. I'd expect that to be the case on others too.

Comment: @Hannu You might want to read [Why I Switched From a Swedish to a US Keyboard](https://derantell.github.io/blog/2013/07/23/why-i-switched-from-a-swedish-to-a-us-keyboard/) ;)

Comment: Heh! ;-)  I've been there considering the switch myself, of the same reason - but somehow I have jumped enough between different keyboards to switch almost automatically as the wrong character appears. I find it harder to use a laptop though ;-)

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the help! Sadly it does not work for me. :( Quotation-Mark itself needs shift pushed down on an US layout.

Comment: @TrudleR Yes, of course it does. That is normal.

Comment: @DavidPostill I tried it in both ways of course, but it doesn't work on my ubuntu VM.

Comment: @TrudleR This is a Windows solution. Your question is sadly lacking any information that you are using Ubuntu in a Windows VM (or Windows in a Ubuntu VM which ever it is).

Comment: I just checked the edit history. I never put that windows tag myself... What the ****. I thought this info isn't needed because this is the same over all OS.

Comment: @TrudleR Why do you think it is not needed? Keyboard behaviour is dependent on OS specific drivers and configuration programs ...

Comment: @DavidPostill if I set the layout "German(Switzerland)" on Windows OR Linux, it is not different at all. So I thought there is an easy standard for umlauts too. I mean: You press shift to write an uppercase letter. This is also the same everywhere.

Comment: You can also get some characters with diacritics by pressing Right-Alt+<char>. Yet using dead keys as described here is the universal way to enter such characters (when using US International keyboard layout). To enter plain "/', you have to press Space after pressing "/'.

Comment: BTW, it's almost 7 years later now and I sticked with this answer ever since. It's the PERFECT solution to all europeans who want to adapt to the american system and also works for MacOS, Windows and Linux!

Answer (score 4):

To expand [DavidPostill's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1142932/445923) for **Windows 10**:

1. Start menu > **Language settings**
2. In **Preferred languages** click on **English (United States)**
3. Click **Options**
4. In **Keyboards** click **Add a keyboard**
5. Choose **United States-International**
6. Go back to language settings
7. Click **Choose an input method to always use as default**
8. In **Override for default input method** choose **English (United States) - United States-International**

Now you can use the international keyboard shortcuts in Windows 10.

Answer (score 1):

If you don`t mind a 3rd party app and want something that is more convenient than switching layouts or using Alt codes, KeyEXT emulates the way Mac does it - holding a key on your keyboard down displays special characters options for most Latin-based European languages, including umlauts and ß. You can then select which character you’d like by hitting the number key for that option (or clicking on it with your mouse). You can also customize what character options are available for each key on your keyboard by selecting any character from Unicode which includes Asian languages, math and thousands of other special symbols.

[Example screenshot - selecting the option 1 will replace the ‘ a ’ with ‘ ä ’](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2M1Bq.png)

You can find the app here: KeyEXT (https://www.microsoft.com/store/apps/9P8X3818K9KT)

There is a free trial so you can try it without having to pay anything to see if it would work for you.

Comment: The question explicitly says that a 3rd party app is not wanted.

Answer (score 0):

I also tried to setup umlauts (äöüß€) on my US layout thinkpad keyboard.

For me it worked like this:

1. use `xev` to determine the keycode of the right side Alt key
2. Setup a ~/.Xmodmap file like so:

```
    ! Map umlauts to PRINT SCREEN + 
keycode 135 = Mode_switch
keysym e = e E EuroSign
keysym a = a A adiaeresis Adiaeresis
keysym o = o O odiaeresis Odiaeresis
keysym u = u U udiaeresis Udiaeresis
keysym s = s S ssharp
```

3. add `xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap` to `~/.bashrc`

I found a more detailed instruction [here](https://www.blunix.com/blog/using-german-umlauts-on-us-layout-keyboards.html), the page also contains a [ISO Latin-1 Table](https://cs.stanford.edu/people/miles/iso8859.html) with all the special characters you can map.